# mysql merge address book from different sources

Tags: php, mysql

I have differents address book in excel format, i have imported all (around 20.000) into a mysql table (address_tmp) now i have many duplicated records and need to remove that and to move the clean records into the mysql table (address_book). The duplicated items its the minus problem the big problem is to choose wich records to delete and to merge some data into ad unique and most complete record.

es.

```
1 | Tom Cruise | tom@cruise.com | +17777777 | category 1
2 | Tom Cruise | empty | +177777777 | category 2
3 | Cruise | tom@cruise.com | empty | category 3
```

i would like to keep record 1 that is the most complete and to merge the categories with this result:

```
1 | Tom Cruise | tom@cruise.com | +17777777 | category 1, category 2, category 3
```

Is it possible by some mysql+php code or it is a work to do by hand.
Thanks

Comment: i still not find a solution somebody can help me? thanks

Comment: i still searching a solutions but didn't find out, can some one help me? thanks